# I have an arbitrary number of lists, how do I zip them together?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have some lists which represent the pixel value for some images which each of the lists are made of 0s and 1s. My question is how can I get the average value of all the elements number zero and represent it in a new list in the same element number and repeat the process for all other elements? (Get the average value for all elements number zero, one, two and …). So the final list should be the same lengths as my all other lists while each element is the average value of all other lists.

Comment: If you just added all the images together and divided by the number of images, then the values in that "average image" would be exactly what you were asking for - if I understand what you are asking for. Which bit of that do you not know how to do?

Comment: Floris; but how can I add the images together get the average of them?

Comment: how can I add images together pixel by pixel?

Comment: Are you wanting to average their colors together or something else? As it is, your written description and code don't quite match in intent

Comment: I see only one list, not an arbitrary number of them and I don't see any attempt to zip anything in your code. I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
averageImage = new image(size of source image)

for each image in list:
   for each pixel in image:
      add pixel to averageImage

averageImage = averageImage / numberOfSourceImages
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. could you please give more explanation on your code? how are you adding list together?

Comment: what should I put as size of source image? is this number of pixels?

Comment: No it is not C# - it is "pseudo code" (as I said in my answer) - that is "not actual code but a way to describe the steps you have to take". I would expect that you should be able to figure it out from here. I don't really have time to write the exact code - I thought this would be enough. Maybe it will inspire someone else to write a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

***I wrote this up but reread your question and realized it probably doesn't meet your requirements.***

Nonetheless, it takes an arbitrary number of `Bitmap` and averages their colors. Just feed it a `List<Bitmap>` and call `ToBitmap()`.

```
public class BitmapAverage {
  private readonly List<Bitmap> _bmps;

  public BitmapAverage(List<Bitmap> bmps) {
    _bmps = bmps;
  }

  private struct ColorAverage {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int G { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
  }

  private Bitmap _averageImages() {
    var colors = new ColorAverage[_bmps.First().Width, _bmps.First().Height];
    foreach (var bmp in _bmps) {
      for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++) {
          var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
          colors[x, y].A += color.A;
          colors[x, y].R += color.R;
          colors[x, y].G += color.G;
          colors[x, y].B += color.B;
        }
      }
    }
    return _toBitmap(colors);
  }

  private Bitmap _toBitmap(ColorAverage[,] colors) {
    var bitmapToReturn = new Bitmap(_bmps[0].Width, _bmps[0].Height, _bmps[0].PixelFormat);
    for (var x = 0; x < colors.GetLength(0); x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < colors.GetLength(1); y++) {
        bitmapToReturn.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(colors[x,y].A / _bmps.Count, 
                                                     colors[x,y].R / _bmps.Count, 
                                                     colors[x,y].G / _bmps.Count, 
                                                     colors[x,y].B / _bmps.Count)
        );
      }
    }
    return bitmapToReturn;
  }

  public Bitmap ToBitmap() {
    return _averageImages();
  }
}
```

[image: img] + [image: img] + [image: img] = [image: img]

Full-size images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc6O8.jpg